# Kubectl get pods that have ready 1/1 and status running

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way to get the pods that have status `Running` and also `ready 1/1`? This is what I tried so far:

```
kubectl get pod -l app=quarkus-jvm --field-selector=status.phase==Running
```

The command above returns also the pods that are not `ready 0/1`. I would like to get only one entry, the one with `ready 1/1`.

[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested this on a playground

Before:

```
[node2 ~]$ kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase==Pending 
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-cctsd   0/1     Pending   0          8m29s
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-hlhlp   0/1     Pending   0          8m29s
```

After

```
 kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase==Pending | grep "66b6c48dd5-cctsd"
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-cctsd   0/1     Pending   0          8m49s
```

The grep command is a way to filter content. You can try with this one command:

```
kubectl get pod -l app=quarkus-jvm --field-selector=status.phase==Running | grep "1/1"
```

Comment: what about multiple containers 2/2, or 4/4.. grep -P can be used, but -P perl checks will not work in some instances..